# How to organize the addCallBack element and when/where is stored the value selected in listbox

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a code that automatic fill in an UI. When i select an item in the list box it lauch a function that looks for data to fill in.
I think the problem comes from the hierarchy: the listbox is in the grid1, the grid1 in the panel. How to use the callbackelement and why... i don't really understand why to use it and the google documentation is not fully.
The click button to add data is running well but i don't understand why changehandler variable is "undefined"
Here is my code:

```
    var submissioSSKey = 'XXXXXX';//Change this key to your spreadsheet key
//creation de l'interface d'ajout des déchets

function addWasteData() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Ajout de déchet').setHeight(400).setWidth(500);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var wasteListSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Registre déchets");
  //1. creation d'une grille pour structurer la app:
  var mypanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('mainPanel'); 
  var grid1 = app.createGrid(2, 3).setId('grid1').setStyleAttribute("border","3px double #CCCCCC");
  var grid2 = app.createGrid(3, 3).setStyleAttribute("border","1px solid #CCCCCC");
  var grid3 = app.createGrid(3, 3).setStyleAttribute("border","1px solid #CCCCCC");
  var grid4 = app.createGrid(3, 3).setStyleAttribute("border","1px solid #CCCCCC");

  //2.Labels informatifs
  grid1.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Déchet'))
  .setWidget(0, 1, app.createLabel('Quantité'))
  .setWidget(0, 2, app.createLabel('Unités'));

  grid2.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Prix'))
  .setWidget(0, 1, app.createLabel('€ / unit'))
  .setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Traitement'))
  .setWidget(1, 1, app.createLabel('Transport'))
  .setWidget(1, 2, app.createLabel('Location'));

  grid3.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Dates'))
  .setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Enlèvement'))
  .setWidget(1, 1, app.createLabel('Facture'))
  .setWidget(2, 1, app.createLabel('Entrée donnée'));

  grid4.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Codes'))
  .setWidget(0, 1, app.createLabel('déchet'))
  .setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Regroupement'))
  .setWidget(1, 1, app.createLabel('Valorisation'))
  .setWidget(1, 2, app.createLabel('Élimination'));
  // text box et listes
  grid1
  .setWidget(1, 0, app.createListBox().setName('waste').setId('waste'))
  .setWidget(1, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('quantity').setId('quantity'))
  .setWidget(1, 2, app.createListBox().setId('unitListBox').setName('unit').addItem("tonnes").addItem("m³"));

  grid2.setWidget(2, 0, app.createTextBox().setName('Trait').setId('trait'))
  .setWidget(2, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('Transport').setId('transport'))
  .setWidget(2, 2, app.createTextBox().setName('Location').setId('location'));

  grid3.setWidget(2, 0, app.createDateBox().setId('enlevement').setName('enlevement'))
  .setWidget(2, 1, app.createDateBox().setId('facture').setName('facture'))
  .setWidget(2, 2, app.createDateBox().setId('inputdb').setName('inputdb'));

  grid4.setWidget(0, 2, app.createTextBox().setName('codedechet').setId('codedechet'))
  .setWidget(2, 0, app.createTextBox().setName('regroupement').setId('regroupement'))
  .setWidget(2, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('valorisation').setId('valorisation'))
  .setWidget(2, 2, app.createTextBox().setName('elimination').setId('elimination'));

  app.createTextBox().setName('info').setId('info');

  //3.définir la variable des éléments de la app pour modification dans le script
  var wasteListBox = app.getElementById("waste").setName('waste');
  var unitListBox = app.getElementById("unitListBox");
  var info = app.getElementById("info");
  var mybutton = app.createButton('Ajouter');
  //4. creation de serveur d'évènement
  // liste deroulante déchet
  var handlerList = app.createServerChangeHandler('selectListHandler');
  handlerList.addCallbackElement(wasteListBox); //est ce bon? c est ici que ça coince
  wasteListBox.addChangeHandler(handlerList);
  // envoi des données
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('insertDataWaste');
  handler.addCallbackElement(mypanel)  //ici ça fonctionne
  mybutton.addClickHandler(handler); 

  //Ajout de les données déchets au menu déroulant, texte box, etc:

  //Ajout des données dans la listbox
   numItemList1 = wasteListSheet.getLastRow()-1;//-1 pour exclure la dernière ligne qui est vide
  //get the item array
  list1ItemArray = wasteListSheet.getRange(2,1,numItemList1,1).getValues();
  //Add the items in ListBox
  for(var i=0; i<list1ItemArray.length; i++){
    wasteListBox.addItem(list1ItemArray[i][0])
  }

  //creation de l'interface et affichage
   mypanel.add(grid1)
  .add(grid2)
  .add(grid3)
  .add(grid4)
  .add(mybutton);
  app.add(mypanel);
  //return app;   <-- ne fonctionne pas :/
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);
}

//test du fonctionnement du choix dans la liste en faisant apparaitre le le choix dans le text box traitement
  function selectListHandler(z)  {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var wasteListBox = z
  var wasteListSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Registre déchets");
  var traitBox = app.getElementById('trait')
  var transport = app.getElementById('transport');
  var location = app.getElementById('location');
  traitBox.setValue(rechercheDechet( wasteListBox,ss,wasteListSheet,11));
  return app;
}

//Insertion des donénes lors du clic sur le boutton de soumission
function insertDataWaste(o){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var intitule = o.parameter.waste;
  var qty = o.parameter.quantity;
  var codeDechet = o.parameter.codedechet;
  var unit = o.parameter.unit;
  var trait = o.parameter.Traitement;
  var trans = o.parameter.Transport;
  var loc = o.parameter.Location;
  var fac = o.parameter.facture;
  var enlev = o.parameter.enlevement;
  var input = o.parameter.inputdb;
  var regr = o.parameter.regroupement;
  var valo = o.parameter.valorisation;
  var elim = o.parameter.elimination;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data"); //.getActiveSheet() supprimé
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 13).setValues([[intitule,codeDechet,qty,unit,trait,trans,loc,fac,enlev,input,regr,valo,elim]]);
  return app;
}
```

And the looking function :

```
function rechercheDechet(value,doc,sheet,column) {
  var sh = sheet;
  var ss = doc;
  var last = sh.getLastRow(); 
  var range = sh.getRange(2, 1, last-1, column).getValues(); 
   {
  for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
    if (range[i] == value) {
      return value;
    }
  }
  return;
}

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution by Serge Insas for search function, thanks to you.
In the listbox, the items added that contains a "+" create a bug. I replaced it by words. Then it was working.

```
 function rechercheDechet(value,doc,sheet,column) {
      var sh = sheet;
      var ss = doc;
      var last = sh.getLastRow(); 
      var lastCol = sh.getLastColumn()
      var range = sh.getRange(2, 1, last-2, lastCol ).getValues(); // on prend toute la ligne de données
      for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
        if (range[i][0].toString().match(value) == value) { // on compare la 1ere colonne avec le nom
        Logger.log('trouvé '+value +'  i='+i)
          return range[i][10]; //et on prend la colonne prix (indice 0 dans le comptage dans une array >> 10 pour col 11) 
        }
      }
      return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's far more easy to use the parent widget as CallBackElement rather than a particular widget...

In your code I would use grid 1 (where you ask the question) like this

```
  handlerList.addCallbackElement(grid1); //est ce bon? c est ici que ça coince
```

instead of

```
handlerList.addCallbackElement(wasteListBox); //est ce bon? c est ici que ça coince
```

since wasteListBox is the list itself you want to populate (I think)... 
Anyway, as a general rule, the callbackelement must contain the widgets that you want to get the values, so the higher in the hierarchy is the best choice. Why not panel1 so you are sure ?

About your comment on `return app` not working, it is normal and clearly explained [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp#DisplayingSpreadsheet)

**EDIT1 :** one more issue I found in your code : the search function (rechercheDechet) return a variable called `value` that is an array and you used it by assigning it to a textBox... this shouldn't work ...

A word of explanation : when you read a range in a spreadsheet using `getValues()` you get a 2 dimension array, then you iterate the array's rows in a for loop to test an equality between an array (1 dimension) and a string value (that will always fail also...). At the end the function returns an array corresponding to the row (a part of it in fact) in the spreadsheet. Note that even if you select only one single column the value will still be 2D, to get rid of that simply use `range[i][0]` for example to get the 1rst cell in the range or `range[i].toString()` to make it ... a string !

J'espère avoir été clair, hoping to be clear enough.
I tried a copy of your code and it seemed to be working with the small changes, although I don't have any data in my SS to show ;-)

**EDIT2 :** there is also another issue, it concerns the function `selectListHandler(z)` that you are calling with a server handler : in this case the variable `z` is the so called `event`, ie an encoded data of what the UI is returning. But you are using `z` '*as it is*' for the first parameter of function `rechercheDechet` which is supposed to be a `range` ... quite a mess there... may I suggest you refer to the [documentation examples](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp?hl=en#ServerHandlers) on event parameters or use the logger to see its content `Logger.log(e.parameter)`. It would be difficult to explain everything in the scope of this answer

Comment: Thank you for your help but i i think it undefined since the begin. I did some modifications in the selectListHandler:  var wasteListBox = z.parameter.waste; it should be running but i have undefined